# I don't understand why minifying slows things down

Tags: php, minify, fat-free-framework

This might be my mistake somewhere, but anyway, I am using the fat free framework which has an inbuilt function to minify multiple css/js into a single file, and I thought that this would be good for optimization, but it turns out the opposite. If I keep the js files separately(and they are at the end of my html), the total size if added, comes to around 364kb, and seems to load in parallel within 1.5 secs. If I try to load the combined version however, the single file size becomes around 343kb, but takes around 10secs to load.

My minifying logic is a bit different though. First in the template I call a function to load the files:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ @BM->minify('js','js/',array(
                                    'vendor/jQui/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js',
                                    'vendor/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js',
                                    'vendor/bootstrap.min.js',
                                    'vendor/smartmenus-0.9.5/jquery.smartmenus.min.js',
                                    'vendor/smartmenus-0.9.5/addons/bootstrap/jquery.smartmenus.bootstrap.min.js',
                                    'vendor/smartmenus-0.9.5/addons/keyboard/jquery.smartmenus.keyboard.min.js',
                                    'plugins.js',
                                    'main.js'
                                )) }}"></script>
```

The function sets the appropriate session variables and returns a path.

```
public function minify($type='',$folderpath='css/',$files=array()){
        $filepaths = implode(",",$files);
        $this->f3->set('SESSION.UI_'.$type,$this->themeRelFolder().'/'.$folderpath); 
        $this->f3->set('SESSION.ReplaceThemePath_'.$type,$this->themeRelFolder());
        $this->f3->set('SESSION.m_'.$type,$filepaths);
        return($this->f3->get('BASE').'/minify/'.$type);
    }
```

The path maps to a controller which calls the minify method and spits out the actual minified content.

```
public function index($f3, $params) {
        $f3->set('UI',$f3->get('SESSION.UI_'.$params['type'])); 
        if($params['type']=='css'){
            echo str_replace("<<themePath>>","../".$f3->get('SESSION.ReplaceThemePath_'.$params['type'])."/",\Web::instance()->minify($f3->get('SESSION.m_'.$params['type'])));
        }else
        {
            echo \Web::instance()->minify($f3->get('SESSION.m_'.$params['type']));
        }
    }
```

I did it this way so that I can minify as many files as the template needed, and also be able to maintain file paths no matter what folder nesting structure inside a theme.

What am I doing wrong?

PS: I am testing this on my local wamp setup, not an actual server, so the load times are obviously different than a actual web server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the engine is re-minifying every time.  I'll bet you just need to setup caching - http://fatfreeframework.com/web#minify :

> To get maximum performance, you can enable the F3 system caching and
>   F3 will use it to save/retrieve file(s) to minify and to save the
>   combined output as well. You can have a look at the Cache Engine User
>   Guide for more details.

http://fatfreeframework.com/quick-reference#cache :

> Cache backend. F3 can handle Memcache module, APC, WinCache, XCache
>   and a filesystem-based cache.
>
> For example: if you'd like to use the memcache module, a configuration
>   string is required, e.g. $f3->set('CACHE','memcache=localhost') (port
>   11211 by default) or $f3->set('CACHE','memcache=192.168.72.72:11212').

Comment: In fatfree framework, the minification is supposed to store it in cache automatically, in the same link you quoted it's written: `minify will grab each file specified in the querystring var named 'files' and combine into 1 output
Save the minified file in F3 cache for 24 hours. future requests for this route will use cached version`

Comment: You haven't posted here whether you have configured caching or not.  According to what you have posted, caching is *not* enabled.  According to the docs `a filesystem-based backend is used as a fallback` *HOWEVER* the docs *also* say the default value for the cache option is false (`Type: bool|string Default: FALSE`), so unless you have specifically called `$f3->set('CACHE',true)` or `$f3->set('CACHE', $cache_mechanism/*memcache=, folder=*/)`, it will not automatically cache those files for you.

Answer (score 1):

You're making it minify those files on the fly every single time a page is loaded. This, obviously, takes time.

Consider minifying once, then just linking to that one file.

Comment: Well, what if each template file has a different set of js files? I would need to create a cached+minified version for each page?

Comment: Yes. It's what I do :p

Comment: Any pointers as to what exactly I can do to achieve this? I am using .ini files to define routes, is it possible to setup caching for a specific route in the ini file?

Comment: @user279988, on your dev server store development version of JS file. On your production server only store the minimized versions.

Comment: I don't use your system so I can't tell you what to do, but on my sysetm I have a core `.js` file that every page uses, and a single file for each page (such as `index.js`, `party.js`, `forum.js`). So I just have two JS files on each page, nothing like the numerous ones you have.